# How to mock DOM element in Jasmine such that the controller can access it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, dom, jasmine

I am trying to mock a DOM element in my jasmine test suite

```
     it('Test changing radio', function () {
        testElement = angular.element("<div><input class='my_radio' type='radio' /></div>");
        testElement.find('input')[0].checked = true;
        var scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile(testElement)(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        console.log(testElement.find('input')[0].checked); // should print true
        myController.changeRadio();
        console.log(testElement.find('input')[0].checked); // should print false

    });
```

In my controller

```
function changeRadio(){
    for(var i = 0; i < angular.element('.testElement').length; i++){
        angular.element('testElement')[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

The console log should return the following

```
true
false
```

Since `myController.changeRadio` changes radio button from true to false, I verified that when running my app it works, however the jasmine test suite did not work. I found out that the controller couldn't find the input element at all. Is there a way to pass in `$compiled` DOM to the controller during testing?

Comment: it's a bad idea to fiddle with html elements from angular controller, rather you could use angular bindings

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your approach is wrong.
You are testing HTML elements in your unit tests but you should not.
Unit testing is for testing code only.
E2E testing with protractor is for testing the HTML interface.

For example, I have ...

```
<button ng-click="controller.fred()">hello</button>
```

In my unit tests I call and test the controller function fred.
In my E2E tests I click the button and make expectations relating to the HTML interface (something is checked or not for example) based on my button clicking.

Hope this helps.